# How to export an Access database to Excel, using Delphi

Tags: delphi, excel-2007, delphi-xe2

Im writing a database application, using Delphi and need to export data from an access database to an Excel spreadsheet. I Could manage the reverse sequence (import excel to access) using a docmd.spreadsheet. Works 100%. But I do not know how to set the parameters for the export. I need help please.

Answer (score 4):

Check this sample code, Also I recommend you which you read the [`DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214134%28office.12%29.aspx) documentation too.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj;

procedure ExportDataAccess(const AccessDb, TableName, ExcelFileName:String);
Const
  acQuitSaveAll             = $00000001;
  acExport                  = $00000001;
  acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9   = $00000008;
  acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12  = $00000009;
var
 LAccess : OleVariant;
begin
 //create the COM Object
 LAccess := CreateOleObject('Access.Application');
 //open the access database
 LAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(AccessDb);
 //export the data
 LAccess.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet( acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, TableName, ExcelFileName, True);
 LAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase;
 LAccess.Quit(1);
end;

begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      ExportDataAccess('C:\Datos\Database1.accdb','Sales','C:\Datos\MyExcelFile.xls');
      Writeln('Done');
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

Comment: I used your previous answer on importing an excel an it worked 100%. I anticipated from that how an export should work. But it did not function properly. Your answer to the problem is the same as what I originally coded. The problem is 1): If the program export to a file that do not exist already, it creates a file. But when I use Excel to open the file, it gives an error: Excel cannot open the file 'Çodes.xlsx'because the file format or the file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file. Can you help?

Comment: if you want to use the 2007 excel format you must pass the  `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml` value which is defined as `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml= $0000000A;` else just rename the file extension to xls.